# Sync Framework: SqlSyncProvider ItemConflicting vs ApplyChangeFailed

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to use design a syncronisation application that syncs changes between different SQL Server databases.

I came up with a design based around receiving the ItemConflicting event, storing the knowledge associated with the conflict, and resolving all conflicts off-line.

However, it seems that I can only get the ApplyChangeFailed event to fire.  Is there some reason why SqlSyncProvider does not use the ItemConflicting event?  Am I just hooking up to the event wrongly?

The reason I care is that the ItemConlficting event allows me to simply log the conflict and continue with the rest of the synchronisation in a way that I can't seem to achieve with the ApplychangeFailed event.

Answer (score 0):

the ApplyChangeFailed is simply raised to indicate a conflict or an error, whether you address the conflict by resolving or specifying which row should win or ignoring it, you should be able to continue with the sync Process.

not sure what you mean by storing the "knowledge", are you referring to sync knowledge or are you referring to the conflicting rows?

the ApplyChangeFailed event parameter has properties to access the conflicting rows if that's what you need. you can then intercept the conflictign rows, then set the ApplyAction to continue or RetryNextSync